# pass the post method data into navbar without <input> tag

Tags: php

I have some pages in the navbar linked together. I would like to use post to pass information between them without using the `tag<intput method='POST'.....>`.
For example, I have navbar with page: Name   Age    Address.

In the page Name.php

```
$query="SELECT code,name FROM people WHERE code=123;
        $query_result = pg_query($conn1, $query);
        echo '<form action=\"Age.php\" method=\"GET\">' ;
        echo 'Reparto:<br>';
        while($row = pg_fetch_assoc($query_result)) { 
                echo '<a href="Age.php code='.$row["code"].'&name='.$row["name"].'">'.$row["name"]. '</a><br>';
                
            };
               echo '</form>';
```

Now I want click Age in navbar and in the url, I see the data passed with post method. My solution doesn't work. How can I do?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried to use JQuery to make this work?

Comment: with php. Can i do this with php?

Comment: You need to see in url data on click event like key=value pair?

Comment: yes i need to see in url data on click event like key=value pair

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [http_build_query()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) like this:

```
$query="SELECT code,name FROM people WHERE code=123;
$query_result = pg_query($conn1, $query);
//echo '<form action=\"Age.php\" method=\"GET\">' ;
echo 'Reparto:<br>';
while($row = pg_fetch_assoc($query_result)) {
    echo '<a href=\"/Age.php?' . http_build_query($row) . '\">' . $row["name"] . '</a><br>';
};
//echo '</form>';
```

Since this is a anchor, it will redirect you to specific address with needed `key=>values` pairs. After you click the anchor you can get all parameters in your `Age.php` script with `$_GET['name']` and `$_GET['code']`.

Also this can be done like this:

```
<?php
$query="SELECT code,name FROM people WHERE code=123;
$query_result = pg_query($conn1, $query);
?>
Reparto:<br>
<?php while($row = pg_fetch_assoc($query_result)): ?>
    <a href="/Age.php?<?= http_build_query($row) ?>"><?= $row["name"] ?></a><br>
<?php endwhile;?>
```

This is more clean variant.